# Internet connection works in latest BigSur but Safari and ping don't

Tags: macos

I have the latest BigSur and I experience wired issue.

When I type `ping www.google.com` or when I try to surf Google (or any other site) from **Safari** it don't work (Safari think forever and ping return `ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Unknown host`.

Now for the interesting part, when I surf using Google Chrome everything works fine (infect I write this question from Chrome even duo ping isn't working ...)

I fixed the DNS server to Google DNS (I did it yesterday, it helped for a day and we again in the same problem today - I doubled check and the DNS is still Google DNS)

I checked the Proxy settings - they are the normal one

I disabled IPV6 automatically.

None of this works yet.

Any ideas?

---------  edited --------

After thorough check the only Application that works is Google accept it all the rest (Safari, Brave Opera etc.) not work

Comment: Does it work on wifi, or what makes you think it is a wired issue?

Comment: Your are running beta software. Report the issue to Apple.

Comment: @tetech I am on a wired connection (the wirdest thing is that Chrom run without a problem, so it some wired problem that effects all the system (ping, Safari) but not the App that use a different logic path (like Chrom))